# Array variable in gitlab CI/CD yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am writing a CI/CD pipeline for terraform to deploy GCP resources.
In terraform code, I got many functionality and Network is one of them. The folder structure of the Network is

```
Network
 VPC
 LoadBalancer
 DNS
 VPN
```

So, I want to loop terraform init, plan and apply commands for all the sub-folder of Network folder. The yml file looks like

```
image:
  name: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest

variables:
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  env: 'prod'
  network_services: ""

stages:
  - init

init:
    stage: init
    script:
    - |
      network_services = ['vpc' 'vpn']
      for service in $network_services[@]
      do
          echo The path is var/$env/terraform.tfvars
      done
```

The above gives me the error:

```
$ network_services = ['vpc' 'vpn'] # collapsed multi-line command
/bin/sh: eval: line 103: network_services: not found
```

Please suggest a way to declare array variable in gitlab CI/CD yml.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your job to something like this:

```yaml
init:
  stage: init
  script:
    - network_services = ('vpc' 'vpn')
    - for service in $network_services[@]
      do
        echo "The path is var/$env/terraform.tfvars
      done
```

I don't believe you can do multi-line commands like that due to the way the the gitlab-runner eval's the entries in the script array, though combining them with `;` has worked for me if I want them on one line.